# Std::forward_list thread safety

Tags: c++, c++11

With reference to the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <forward_list>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;


class Cache {
    // thread safe, only 1 writer, thanks to mutex
    int add(int val)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mtx);
        if(flSize == 0)
        {
            fl.push_front(val);
            backIt = fl.begin();
        }
        else
        {
            backIt = fl.insert_after(backIt,val);
        }
        ++flSize;
        return flSize - 1;
    }
    // allow concurrent readers (with other readers and writer)
    // get the element at idx into the forward linked list
    // the thread calling get() will never try to index past the last 
    // index/value it pushed to list. It uses the return value from add() as 
    // the arg to get
    // a.k.a get will never be called before an add() has been called, and 
    // if add has been called N times, the index to get will be [0, N)
    int get(int idx)
    {
        int num = 0;
        auto it = fl.cbegin();
        while(num < idx)
        {
            ++num;
            ++it;
        }
        return *it;
    }

    private:

    std::forward_list<int> fl;
    size_t flSize {0};
    std::forward_list<int>::iterator backIt;
    std::mutex mtx;

};
```

The goal is to have readers read from any node in the linked list that has been constructed fully.

**Thoughts:**
This seems to be thread safe(under the aforementioned constraints). I *think* am relying on the implementation details to achieve this behavior. I am not sure if something can go wrong here or if any of my assumptions are incorrect. Is this code portable (across compilers) and is this future proof? Might break if future implementation changes.

**Question**:
can I access the data for a node in a `std::forward_list` in a thread while another thread is performing `std::forward_list::insert_after` on the same node?

Does the standard provide any guidelines for such a scenario?

Comment: If a thread has an iterator, it (probably) can be dereferenced while another thread is inserting, but incrementing it is a no-no.

Comment: @n.m. I feel like this is relying on implementation detail, lets say if these (somehow) did NOT have different addresses then we could have an issue, no? or am I overthinking?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can access a node in one thread while adding another in another thread. You only get in trouble if you try to access data that is being modified, but `insert_after` doesn't modify the data in existing nodes nor does it move any node around. [No iterators or references are invalidated.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/insert_after)

As long as you don't expose a "remove" function or access to iterators (so no thread can iterate through the list while something is being inserted), this is fine. However, I don't see the point of the member `backIt`: it is only accessed (and modified) when the mutex is locked, so it is effectively the same as `fl.end()`. If `std::forward_list` had a `size` method, `flSize` would also be redundant.

A couple suggestions to end with. First, I would suggest against using a linked list to begin with. If you can reserve enough elements or if you can deal with resizing (while locked for readers) when necessary, I would just use a vector or perhaps a vector of pointers if the items are very big. If the reserve or resize cannot be done, I would use a `std::deque`. Second, if you really want to use a `std::forward_list`, I would use `push_front` instead, and return an iterator (possibly const) in `add` that the user can later pass to `get`. That way, no need any complex logic in either of these functions, and `flSize` can also be removed. Though `get` could also be removed since the iterator provides access to the data. Unless there is something more to your comment "It uses the return value from add() as the arg to get".

Comment: I am reading node N and inserting after node N. `insert_after` should modify the `nextPtr` right?
`std::forward_list` doesn't have a `size()` method.

Comment: I can get rid of `backIt` thought

Comment: Good point, I thought it had `size` because `std::list` does. You're also correct about the "next pointer" in the node, but that's an implementation detail and the data itself (what you can see) isn't changed in any way.

Comment: yeah I am wondering if relying on this implementation detail is "OK" or not :|

Comment: You aren't relying on implementation detail. You are relying on the fact that the "nodes" don't move (iterators and references aren't invalidated) and that you are not modifying existing data.

Comment: I need to be non blocking for readers, so I can not use `std::vector`

Comment: @PYA If you use a vector of pointers and return these pointers in `add`, you can. You would need to block when iterating, but that's not mentioned in the question. Or you can use a `std::deque`.

Comment: I think I mentioned it here: `allow concurrent readers (with other readers and writer)`

Comment: @PYA I meant the iterating part isn't mentioned. I don't know how `Cache` is supposed to be used, but it seems a little strange to me that you can only access elements through `get`.